# array-contains-any not working with orderBy and ">= <=" on Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been struggling with Firestore queries.

This is my structure:
[image]

I'm simply trying to fetch data where any item of a set of categories belongs to any entry.

So, I'm doing something like it:

```
 firebaseQuery(
      entriesRef,
      where("categories", "array-contains-any", ["link"])
      where("date", ">=", "{SOME DATE BEFORE 01/01/2023}")
      orderBy("date", "desc")
    )
```

But result is always empty. Any idea of what could going on?

Thanks!

*EDIT*

Important information, I've made some tests and seems the getDocs(query) promise is never resolved or rejected (according to logs)

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: @Rodrigo Borba Can you have a look at my answer?

Answer (score 0):

First I didn’t find any `firebaseQuery` in docs so I have recreated the setup from the provided code and just replaced the `firebaseQuery` with a `query` from the official [firebase/firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array-contains-any) package.

Here’s the updated code :

```
import { collection, getDocs, orderBy, query, where } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "./firebase.js";

const ref = collection(db, "entries");
const start = new Date();
console.log(start);
const q = query(
  ref,
  where("categories", "array-contains-any", ["link"]),
  where("date", ">=", start),
  orderBy("date", "desc")
);

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data().categories, doc.data().date.toDate());
});
```

Comment: Sorry for this late reply, this is a personal project and I've been out of time to invest on it. I'll try that asap and will get back here to report the result